# How to use unlimitedStorage in chromeapp?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am a beginner and trying to make a chrome app. My chrome app has persistent needs and will therefore use an indexed db. Also, I want the app to have unlimitedStorage.

I am using

```
chrome.storage.sync
chrome.storage.local
```

to set and get values.

In my manifest file, when I use "unlimitedStorage" I get an error saying that sync ,local is undefined.

But, in my manifest file, if I use "storage" i don't get any errors.

Can anyone let me know how to do this?

Comment: you need to use both permissions at the same time if you want to use chrome.storage.local with no memory limit.

Comment: you mean my manifest file will look like                                          "permissions":["storage","unlimitedStorage"]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`"storage"` is a permission which give you access to the `chrome.storage` APIs.

`"unlimitedStorage"` removes maximum size limits from storage APIs that are storing data locally, on user disk (`chrome.storage.local` or IndexedDB). It is impossible to increase the quota for `chrome.storage.sync` that way, since it stores data somewhere in the cloud.

So if you want to lift quota for `chrome.storage.local`, you'll have to have both `"storage"` and `"unlimitedStorage"` permissions.

Comment: Your reasoning about why `unlimitedStorage` does not apply to `sync` is correct, but not also that `unlimitedStorage` does *not* apply to `localStorage` (for different reasons): https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=58985

Comment: @apsillers nice catch, official doc is kind of foggy, so I've assumed that if it works for app cache, IDB and chrome.storage , it also should work for localStorage

Comment: It works for `storage.local` but not for `localStorage`. `storage.local` is for chrome extensions, `window.localStorage` is the common web/js API that can be used in background/event pages.