# How to store images in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying store the og images and the apple-touch-icons of the websites in my chrome extension. Is there a way I can do that? I don't want to store their URLs because I don't want the users to download them every time.

Comment: You can store a string `data:` URL of the image contents inside any storage or ArrayBuffer in IndexedDB.

Comment: can I use unlimitedStorage permission with chrome.storage.local to store the data: URL? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35918802/how-to-use-unlimitedstorage-in-chromeapp). Is it necessary to use IndexedDB?

Comment: You can, but it's much slower than IndexedDB so it won't work well with big images.